# border property makes the navigation move slightly

Tags: html, css, menu, hover, border

Ref the following: -

https://romantic-carson-980e19.netlify.com/

Can someone please tell me how to prevent the navigation links from moving slightly when hovering? It is to do with the border-right property but I cannot work out how to prevent it. 
I have tried making the border: none on hover state, I have also tried border 1 px solid transparent on both the li and the a tag. I have also tried googling but cannot find anything.

Also can you please tell me how to remove the border-right as soon as the cursor goes onto the list item (as soon as it goes red, then make the border invisible/disappear).

Ps please advise what you would have typed in google to find this solution - its probably the terminology I used when googling as it will be on there somewhere but it would be good from my own learning perspective as to what one of you guys would have typed in if you were stuck in my situation.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with us — opening external links could be dangerous, and they can go stale. But from what you are describing, using the transparent border "trick" should do. We can better assist once you've share a bare minimum case of your issue here (SO Snippet is preferred).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS bottom border hover "jitter"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29859343/css-bottom-border-hover-jitter)

Comment: Try adding the border rule on the selector "menu li a" not the hover pseudo selector

Answer (score 1):

Adding a border where there was none will cause the size of the element to grow by 2x (left + right, top + bottom). 
Your border on hover is transparent, so what's the purpose?

If you want to change the border color on hover, start with the transparent border, then simply change the border color on hover:

```
li a {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

li a:hover {
  border-color: white;
}
```

Alternatively, you could add the border and a negative margin to offset it, eg:

```
li a {
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin: -1px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I already have a border on the a tag within the li and part of my problem was that i had the border: 1px solid transparent on the [li a] hover state - once I removed the transparent border from the hover then the "jitter was no longer there". Now I have the problem where on hover I can still see the border-right which I no longer want to be visible when I have hovered over the menu item but I do want it visible when the mouse is not hover'd over the menu item. - Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you for this! The margin offset worked great.